# Count max number of pixels for image in GEE and then calculte numbers from this number

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter

I have a code that creates image collection and then calculate what is the biggest number of pixels in image (e.g the image with maximum spatial data).
I managed to calculte this number and to use it to create new image collection with relevant images.
I want to create range of numebr of pixels that are needed in an image in order to join this image collection. I decided that I can "accept" images that are at least 75% size of the biggest image.
I have a code for that, but whenever I try to compute max_number.multiply(0.75) I get error:

> max_number.multiply is not a function

Those are therelevant parts from my code:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2019-12-02')
                  .select('B4', 'B5','pixel_qa')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(maskL8sr);

//clip the dataset according to the geometry
var clippedCol=dataset.map(function(im){ 
  return im.clip(geometry);
});

// Get the number of images.
var count = clippedCol.size();
print('Count: ',count);

//here I do calculations -clip image collection, add NDVI so my new
//my new dataset called now "withNDVI"

//Filter according to number of pixels

var ndviWithCount = withNDVI.map(function(image){
  var countpixels = ee.Number(image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: geometry,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 30,
  }).get('NDVI'));

  return image.set('count', countpixels);
});


print('NDVIwithCount:',ndviWithCount);

var max = ndviWithCount.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.max(),  ["count"]);
print(max.get('max'));
var max_number=(max.get('max'));
var almost_max=max_number.multiply(0.75);
```

My end goal is to be able to compute numbers with my var max_number so in the end my script knows automatically for every polygon to choose only the correct images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, boil down your script as much as possible and always include a link to a working script when posting a question. Your changes of getting an answer will increase dramatically!

`ee.ImageCollection.reduceColumns()` returns an `ee.Dictionary`. Calling `ee.Dictionary.get()` returns an `ee.Element`. You will need to cast that element to whatever type it actually is, or use one of the convenience getters which does the casting for you - `getArray()`, `getGeometry()`, `getNumber()`, `getString()`.

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2019-12-02')
  .filterBounds(Map.getBounds(true))

var max = collection.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.max(), ['system:time_start'])
var max_number=max.getNumber('max')
var almost_max=max_number.multiply(0.75)
print(almost_max)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d5715478172063fc0e990dd08f78cc64